# Hand-soldering stripline opposed emitter transistors

Tags: soldering, soe

I'm used to soldering through-hole parts, and older stuff than that.

I'm seriously considering embarking on an RF power project, that will require the use of stripline opposed emitter transistors (old Motorola MRF-series parts).  These are the things with a circular ceramic body, four rectangular metal tabs, and (usually) a threaded rod out the bottom that is attached to the heatsink.

I've never soldered anything like them before.  Anyone have any good tips, or pointers to tips?

The old [MRF454](http://www.macomtech.com/datasheets/MRF454.pdf) is one example.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the device?

Comment: Link provided.  That's just one example.  The MRF422, MRF428, MRF161 (power MOSFET) are other examples.

Comment: what does "stripline" refer to? Regarding the soldering, they don't look too difficult - just keep wire lengths short as usual for RF.

Comment: Someone able to answer the question will know what stripline is; those merely curious can research.

Comment: That's interesting.  One guy posted a useful answer, that was almost exactly what I was looking for.  The answer gathered downvotes, but no comments to explain why the downvotes, and now the useful answer has been pulled.  Meanwhile, no other answers have shown up.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm  The deleted post was from someone who was banned from this site for inappropriate behavior, but still insists on trying to be relevant.

Comment: And sabotaging answers is appropriate?  This is a technical site, it's supposed to be about information, not a egos.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.  BTW your profanity has been flagged.  I might happily upvote a good answers of yours any moment though.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  I, on the other hand, am glad that I feel that way.  Not sorry at all.

Comment: I can think of a few regulars who meet your "inconsiderate" but "technically well versed" - what do you propose to do about them?

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Follow the rules set forth for this board.

Comment: I do.  But what do you propose we do about those who downvote newbie questions in ways that they **admit** are not in accordance with the site rules?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10509/discussion-between-nick-alexeev-and-chris-stratton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book called [Radio Frequency Transistors, Second Edition: Principles and Practical Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750672811) (ISBN 0750672811) that has a section on mounting and soldering SOE RF power transistors. This is a summary of the most important points made in the book:

- Use a relatively thin layer of thermal paste on the heatsink area of the transistor to prevent the flange bowing up.
- Physically mount the transistor with a flat washer on top of the package and a split lock washer on the other side of the PCB or heatsink.
- Be careful not too apply to much to torque to the fasteners because it stops the flange from expanding with heat. This ends up giving worse thermal contact than not enough torque.
- Try to keep the leads as close as possible to the PCB tracks to minimise inductance.
- You should fasten the transistor in place before soldering.
- When soldering use apply a generous amount of solder to leech most of the gold from the leads to help prevent a brittle joint.

I've only ever soldered a couple of these devices but a technique that worked well for me was a reasonably large chisel tip and 1mm solder swiped outwards while applying a light pressure on top with a pair of pliers in the other hand. Then I just quickly worked back over the top of the pin with more solder right along top to keep the solder molten the whole time with a delay in between each pin.

That was with a package with long flexible leads that sat flush so your mileage may vary with some other packages. Doing a Google image search on MRF454 will show a few techniques, some appear to use the method I've described while others appear to just concentrate on soldering the ends of the leads. It will of course also depend on your PCB and whether you have copper underneath the full length of the pins.